# Apple external Keyboard A1243 does not work properly

Tags: keyboard

My Apple external German wired keyboard A1243 does not work properly.

When I press the <kbd>space</kbd> or <kbd>m</kbd>, it becomes `m` (space + m).  When I press <kbd>u</kbd> it becomes `u` and sometimes `ü`.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

At minimum, your keyboard needs to be cleaned.  More than likely, it needs to be replaced.

Just doing a [quick search](https://www.bing.com/search?q=keyboard+sending+multiple+charachters) for your symptoms brings up tons of relevant results in which a majority of the keyboards needed to be replaced.  Some were fixed by a cleaning, but that requires taking the keyboard apart.

But to be certain it is your keyboard and not you computer, just plug the keyboard into another computer; if the problem persists then it's time for a new one.